# volver al valor por default defaultChecked al limpiar formulario

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

actualmente estoy trabajando en un formulario en react js, pero cuando necesito limpiar mi formulario, no me queda el valor por default en checkbox, como puedo hacer esto?

```
var Checkbox = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {checked: false}
  },
  handleCheck: function() {
    this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked});
  },
  render: function() {
    var msg;
    if (this.state.checked) {
      msg = "Checked";
    } else {
      msg = "Un-checked";
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleCheck} defaultChecked={this.state.checked}/>
        <p>Checkbox: {msg}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Nos podrías compartir el código donde limpias tu formulario ?, de esa te podremos ayudar de una mejor manera.

Comment: lo que hago es un clearFilter, mediante un setState asignarle de nuevo un valor, pero ese es mi problema, porque el componente mira el state y no el defaultChecked

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar el código completo ?